# Android: displaying part of a message in a TextView

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I have a list view where each list item is a message with a sender/recipient, date, and content. I want to display the sender/recipient in the top left, the date in the top right, and the content on another line below. My problem is that if either the name or content is too long I want to be able to cut off the string and end it with an ellipsis (...). Is there any way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Or programmatically

```
myTextView.setEllipsize (TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
```

For my details: [android:ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize)

Comment: @coffee But I am getting TextUtils cannot be resolved to a type error message. Do I need to include any .jar library?

Answer (score 1):

Use java! You could add extra features, like detecting the end of a word.

```
if (mystring.length() > LIMIT) {
    mystring = mystring.substring(0, LIMIT) + "...";
}
```